# How do I draw multinomial distributed samples with RcppArmadillo?

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

The problem is that I have a variable `arma::mat prob_vec` and want something equivalent to `rmultinom(1, 1, prob_vec)` in R.

I found the `rmultinom` function provided by RcppArmadillo has a weird argument requirement which is different from that in R! So it won't pass the compilation.

I just wanna know how to draw the desired sample in RcppArmadillo, or equivalently in Armadillo. If I need to get the pointer or convert my `prob_vec` variable, please tell me how.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your friendly neighbourhood co-author of `RcppArmadillo` here:  I can assure you that it does not provide `rmultinom`, but Rcpp does.  In fact, it simply passes through to R itself as a quick `grep` would have told you:

```
  inline void rmultinom(int n, double* prob, int k, int* rn) 
         { return ::rmultinom(n, prob, k, rn); }
```

So I would suggest your first write a five-line C program against the R API to make sure you know how to have `rmultinom` do what you want it to do, and then use Rcpp and RcppArmadillo to do the same thing on the data in your vector.

Comment: Thanks much, Dirk! I'm sure you are among the most friendly and helpful (if you identify yourself as) consultant I've met.