# Using rmultinom with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, bayesian, mcmc

I'd like to use the R function **rmultinom** in c++ code to be used with Rcpp.  I get an error about not enough arguments - I am unfamiliar with what these arguments ought to be, as they do not corresond to the arguments used with the function in R.  I also didn't have any luck using the "::Rf_foo" syntax to access an R function from Rcpp code.

Here is a simplified version of my code below (yes, I am writing a gibbs sampler).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>                                                                                                                                     
using namespace Rcpp;                                                                                                                                 

// C++ implementation of the R which() function.                                                                                                      
int whichC(NumericVector x, double val) {                                                                                                             
  int ind = -1;                                                                                                                                       
  int n = x.size();                                                                                                                                   
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {                                                                                                                       
    if (x[i] == val) {                                                                                                                                
      if (ind == -1) {                                                                                                                                
        ind = i;                                                                                                                                      
      } else {                                                                                                                                        
        throw std::invalid_argument( "value appears multiple times." );                                                                               
      }                                                                                                                                               
    } // end if                                                                                                                                       
  } // end for                                                                                                                                        
  if (ind != -1) {                                                                                                                                    
    return ind;                                                                                                                                       
  } else {                                                                                                                                            
    throw std::invalid_argument( "value doesn't appear here!" );                                                                                      
    return -1;                                                                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                     

// [[Rcpp::export]]                                                                                                                                   
int multSample(double p1, double p2, double p3) {                                                                                                     
  NumericVector params(3);                                                                                                                            
  params(0) = p1;                                                                                                                                     
  params(1) = p2;                                                                                                                                     
  params(2) = p3;                                                                                                                                     

  // HERE'S THE PROBLEM.                                                                                                                              
  RObject sampled = rmultinom(1, 1, params);                                                                                                          
  int out = whichC(as<NumericVector>(sampled), 1);                                                                                                    
  return out;                                                                                                                                         
}
```

I am new to c++, so I realize that alot of this code is probably nooby and inefficient. I'm open to suggestions on how to improve my c++ code, but my priority is hearing about the rmultinom business. Thanks!

Btw, I apologize for similarity with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653336/how-do-i-draw-multinomial-distributed-samples-with-rcpparmadillo), but

1. The answer didn't work for my purposes
2. The difference may be enough to warrant a different question (do you think so? )
3. The question was posted and answered a year ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are the answer by user95215 amended so that it compiles, and another version more in the Rcpp style:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector oneMultinomC(NumericVector probs) {
    int k = probs.size();
    SEXP ans;
    PROTECT(ans = Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, k));
    probs = Rf_coerceVector(probs, REALSXP);
    rmultinom(1, REAL(probs), k, &INTEGER(ans)[0]);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(ans);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector oneMultinomCalt(NumericVector probs) {
    int k = probs.size();
    IntegerVector ans(k);
    rmultinom(1, probs.begin(), k, ans.begin());
    return(ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I attempt to compile your code, I get the compiler error:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('~/scratch/multSample.cpp')
multSample.cpp:33:21: error: no matching function for call to 'rmultinom'
  RObject sampled = rmultinom(1, 1, params);
                    ^~~~~~~~~
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rmath.h:449:6: note: candidate function not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 3 were provided
void    rmultinom(int, double*, int, int*);
        ^
1 error generated.
```

As it suggests, you haven't specified the arguments correctly. Note that the `rmultinom` interface is a bit awkward compared to other functions: it fills the memory pointed at by `*rn`, rather than returning a new object (with its own freshly allocated memory).

If you look in [the R sources](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/rmultinom.c) you'll see the interface, and you can see an example of it being used [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/random.c#L299-L335) as well (in fact, `stats` makes a wrapper function that does some more argument checking and whatnot). But notice how it's used here:

```
rmultinom(size, REAL(prob), k, &INTEGER(ans)[ik]);
```

In other words, it's filling an `INTSXP` called `ans` by passing that address of that memory on to the `rmultinom` function.

So if you want to use this function from `Rcpp`, you'll have to do something similar -- but perhaps this deserves a similar sugar vectorization treatment to avoid the ugliness of that interface.

You might try doing something like:

```
IntegerMatrix sampled(nrow, ncol);
rmultinom(1, 1, params, sampled.begin());
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks, the links you provided helped me figure out an answer that worked. I will post an answer detailing that code (forgive me if that is not in agreement with custom).

Answer (score 0):

The example and links provided by Kevin enabled me to find an answer that worked. There was some wrangling of types. I wrote a function that allows you to sample one vector from a multinomial distribution. The code is below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector oneMultinomC(NumericVector probs) {
    int k = probs.size();
    SEXP ans;
    PROTECT(ans = RF_allocVector(INTSXP, k));
    probs = RF_coerceVector(probs, REALSXP);
    rmultinom(1, REAL(probs), k, &INTEGER(ans)[0]);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return ans;
}
```

I don't understand half of what is going on here. Particularly, I don't understand the fourth argument to 'rmultinom'. I know that it is a pointer to a memory location of where to store the output, but I don't understand the '[0]' bit.  Nonetheless, it works. Gibbs sample away, boys and girls.

Comment: I think you could also write that in more Rcpp-idiomatic style without `SEXP` or the `PROTECT` business...